# Riot Police crashing on Mission 14

Tags: riot-police

Riot Police fails when I reach mission 14 since I've started using Windows 10 (some error related to biospike_PCX.DLL).

[image]

[image]

Running it with compatibility mode didn't solve the problem.

How can I skip mission 14?

Riot Police is a real-time strategy game with 16 missions and one secret bonus mission.

It's a game that simulates the work of police forces that needs to secure urban areas during events that involves the gathering of lots people.

The game provides:

- basic police units (fast) that can arrest or beat-down protestors;
- police units (slow) with a shield and who can form a wall to close a street;
- enforcer units who use flashball firearms or similar;
- cavalry units (very fast) that has a strong presence and is equiped with Gas bombs;
- riot vehicules (slow) that throws water with high capacity to neutralize riots

[image]

Comment: What game are you talking about?

Comment: This one: https://www.igdb.com/games/riot-police

Comment: @MohamedEnnahdiElIdrissi  can you specify on what game it really is? Nobody seemed to know what you are talking about, since the game is not that popular. You can add a short paragraph on what game it is about and add pictures in to let us know what is it about.

Comment: @MrCreeper done!

Comment: Can you also show a picture of the error?

Comment: @snoozingnewt I added a screenshot from Windows events log. Sorry it's in French.

Comment: Does this site help? https://errortools.com/windows/fix-windows-10-error-code-0xc00000fd/